# Shifting binary string to a canonical form

Tags: binary, bit-shift

I need to compare binary strings but I consider them to be the same if one is a circular shift of the other. For example, I need the following to be the same:

```
10011, 11100, 01110, 11001
```

I think it'll be easier to store them in a canonical way, and just check for equivalence. All strings to be compared has the same length (might be more than 100 bits), so I'll keep the length unchanged, and define the canonical form as the smallest binary number we can get from a circular shift. For example, `00111` is the canonical form of the binary strings shown above.

My question is, **given a binary string, how can I circular shift it to get the smallest binary number** without checking all possible shifts?

If other representation would be better, I'd be happy to receive suggestions.

I'll add, that flipping the string also doesn't matter, so the canonical form  of `010011` is `001101` (if as described above) but if flipping is allowed, the canonical form should be `001011` (which I prefer). A possible solution is just to compute the canonization of the string and of the flipped string and choose the smaller.

If it helps, I'm working in MATLAB with binary vectors, but no need for code, an explanation of a way to solve that will be enough, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Find the longest sequence of 0s, if > 1 shift until the first is the msb.

oops edge case would be 00100, so if you have two equal longest sequences of zeros, you'd want the only possible 1 as the lsb as well.

Find the longest sequence of 1s, if > 1 shift until the last is the lsb

If there are no consecutive 1s or 0s shift until the lsb is 1

That said it's only five shifts so the brute force way you know will work could easily be less effort...

Comment: Thanks! actually the strings length might be more than 100 bits (I've updated the question), but finding consecutive 0s is certainly something I'm considering

Comment: Well you can always go for longest 0s then 1s (in one loop, if they aren't happening then drop to brute force.